# ibc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsexception

when i run my app, i received this error :

```
2014-11-10 06:14:05.581 Yoga[4032:110484] user is registered
2014-11-10 06:14:30.552 Yoga[4032:110484] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
* First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c999f35 exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c632bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   UIKit                               0x000000010b43e16a -[UIStoryboardPushSegue destinationContainmentContext] + 0
    3   UIKit                               0x000000010aedc8be -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010afe3410 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010afe27df -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010af22308 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010af22c33 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 683
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010aeef9b1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010aefca7d _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17370
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010aed8103 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1961
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c8cf551 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION + 17
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c8c541d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c8c4a54 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c8c4486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010d3329f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010aedb420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    17  Yoga                                0x000000010a840b53 main + 115
    18  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010f69b145 start + 1
    19  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

somebody can help me pls

Comment: The title of this question does not match the content.  Please fix it.

Comment: Where did you put a Push Segue with no `UINavigationController`?

Comment: @Larme Sorry I'm beginner for Xcode. Do you mean the Navigation Controller before the initial view?

Answer (score 0):

add Navigation Controller to your initial view

Select the initial view
Go To Editor--> Embed In --> Navigation Controller.

Comment: I have a Navigation Controller to my initial view.